# React protected route Issue without logout redirect on Login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

i m building react login app with  react protected route jwt authnetication  my login component working  fine but when i go to dashboard and  i update the url manually its redirect me login page without logout.

```
  const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {  
    //const auth = useSelector(state => state.auth)   
    let auth =   localStorage.getItem('token')   
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(null) 

    useEffect(() => {
        let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
            if(token){
                let tokenExpiration = jwtDecode(token).exp;
                let dateNow = new Date();
                   console.log(tokenExpiration)
                if(tokenExpiration < dateNow.getTime()/1000){
                    setIsAuthenticated(false)
                }else{
                    setIsAuthenticated(true)
                }
            } else {
               setIsAuthenticated(false)
            }
        // eslint-disable-next-line   }, [auth])

      if(isAuthenticated === null){
        return <></>   }

      return (
        <Route {...rest} render={props =>
          !isAuthenticated ? (
            <Redirect to='/login'/>
          ) : (
          )
        }
      />   ); };
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. You can use the private route separate file

## PrivateRoute.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            localStorage.getItem('token')
                ? <Component {...props} />
                : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login'}} />
        )} />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

## Route.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/Login/Login'
import { PrivateRoute } from "./PrivateRoute";
import Dashboard from "./components/Home/Dashboard";
import Notfound from './Notfound';

class Routes extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
        <React.Fragment>

        <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} label="Home"/>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="*" component={Notfound} />
        </Switch>

        </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default Routes;
```

Comment: your answer look logical when i tried its give me  this error Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.thanx for your valuable response how i get out of this situation..please help me

Comment: use private route is separate. I updated my latest code